# Removing the last part of the data

Tags: php, sockets, hex

I am receiving this data via socket that was sent by our device

```
$$\111,01234567,Z00,14062604556_C1E01.jpg,23,0,ÿØÿÛ„ /9)+"/D«b“Ç$=Œ©ÇCL8F(ßyN -1¤¦E%4œÒ( ž«øžÔ¥©HÂ‚Û«55ŠÆHi9êZ´‹!¡ e!}M7‡'ÐTËVTt‰Øa À÷4áopøÆ€vÓæ‡ý‘ÈÃNØÿe@£ìŠÍpØúŠWˆ<«Eë!?­¤{¾«šI€¾|#îÃú >Ô†Z/píRú ü) ÄÇøÈú Aq<Ùç«þtnsÕÛó4 áÏ­QK@VlWýk}E‰¼l€ãw‰=‚úÐXüSâ“ð¤ØÿÐë¶œ{ÓÂháF1KLŠ( Šk t*G³Þ6^Œ)‚YFde ýÕïõ¨*71
```

And I want to remove this last `*71`

Comment: Are you always removing last 3 chars? Try `substr($string, 0, -3);`

Comment: Or if you only need to remove last 3 chars when trey are `*71`, try `rtrim($string, '*71');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$str = (substr($str, 0, -3);
```

For more information see: [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr` to remove, Check following

```
$str='$$\111,01234567,Z00,14062604556_C1E01.jpg,23,0,ÿØÿÛ„ /9)+"/D«b“Ç$=Œ©ÇCL8F(ßyN -1¤¦E%4œÒ( ž«øžÔ¥©HÂ‚Û«55ŠÆHi9êZ´‹!¡ e!}M7‡\'ÐTËVTt‰Øa À÷4áopøÆ€vÓæ‡ý‘ÈÃNØÿe@£ìŠÍpØúŠWˆ<«Eë!?­¤{¾«šI€¾|#îÃú >Ô†Z/píRú ü) ÄÇøÈú Aq<Ùç«þtnsÕÛó4 áÏ­QK@VlWýk}E‰¼l€ãw‰=‚úÐXüSâ“ð¤ØÿÐë¶œ{ÓÂháF1KLŠ( Šk t*G³Þ6^Œ)‚YFde ýÕïõ¨*71';

echo $str=substr($str,0,-3); //it will removes last 3 characters
```